# Creating a git commit id file in the project build folder using CMake

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

1. First, I define the `COMMIT_ID` variable:

```
    execute_process(COMMAND git rev-parse HEAD
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE COMMIT_ID )
```

2. If you specify the `COMMIT_ID` variable the project is not built:

```
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${APP_NAME} POST_BUILD
        WORKING_DIRECTORY
            $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${APP_NAME}>
        DEPENDS
            ${COMMIT_ID}
        COMMAND
            ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ${COMMIT_ID} > ./version.md
        COMMENT
            "Generating file version.md"
        VERBATIM)
```

3. But, if you specify a static string the project is built without errors:

```
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${APP_NAME} POST_BUILD
        WORKING_DIRECTORY
            $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${APP_NAME}>
        DEPENDS
            ${COMMIT_ID}
        COMMAND
            ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "COMMIT_ID" > ./version.md
        COMMENT
            "Generating file version.md"
        VERBATIM)
```

Comment: One note, I think the `DEPENDS` argument works when it is a *target name*, or file name, or path. I don't think it'll work as intended when you provide a **variable** to `DEPENDS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with using the `${COMMIT_ID}` variable is that it may contain *trailing whitespace or newlines* from its creation in [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/execute_process.html). You can add the `OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE` argument to cleanup the output of `execute_process` before it is used in the variable:

```
execute_process(COMMAND git rev-parse HEAD
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE COMMIT_ID
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
```